Possibility to obtain an explicit sequence formula of the sequence of numbers in which the next element depends on the two previous elements.
There is a sequence of numbers 0, 1, 1.5, 2.250, 2.875, 3.5625, 4.21875, ..., where the next element depends on the two previous elements
$a_{n} = \frac{1}{2} \times (a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}) + a_{2}$
Is it possible to obtain an explicit sequence formula for $n>2$ ($n\geq 3$) if $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$ are known (not $a_{n-1}$, $a_{n-2}$)
Visually this can be represented as follows:

Many thanks for the answer with an explanation to user @Abezhiko. For those who are interested in the algorithm for solving such problems, here is a link to Wikipedia on this topic: Linear recurrence with constant coefficients

I've tried to fix some of your formatting to make it more readable. Please check that the original meaning has not been lost. It is a really good idea to use LaTeX to correctly render your expressions...

Check if this would be of any help: https://study.com/learn/lesson/solving-recurrence-relations-equation-uses-examples.html

This is an inhomogeneous second-order linear recurrence relation with constant coefficents. It can be solved with the same methods used for differential equations, because it constitute a discrete analog. In this case, the general solution $a_n = b_n + c_n$ will be made of the general solution to the associated homogeneous problem, denoted here by $b_n$, and a particular solution to the original equation, denoted by $c_n$.
The homogeneous problem, namely $b_n = \frac{1}{2}(b_{n-1}+b_{n-2})$, can be transformed through the ansatz $b_n = r^n$ into the corresponding characteristic equation $r^2 = \frac{1}{2}(r+1)$, whose roots are $r = 1$ and $r = -\frac{1}{2}$, hence $b_n = A\cdot1^n + B\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = A + (-2)^{-n}B$, with $A$ and $B$ some constants to be determined with the help of the initial conditions $a_1$ and $a_2$ at the end. We see that the alternating pattern you found comes from the factor $(-2)^{-n}$.
Now, since the inhomogeneous term $a_2$ is a constant, one cannot take a constant ansatz for the particular solution, because it wouldn't be different from the the first homogeneous solution, that is why we will try $c_n = \alpha n$. It must satisfy $\alpha n = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha(n-1) + \alpha(n-2)) + a_2$, which leads to $\alpha = \frac{2}{3}a_2$.
In conclusion, one has $a_n = b_n + c_n = A + (-2)^{-n}B + \frac{2}{3}a_2n$. Finally, the initial conditions imply the following system of equation :
$$
\begin{cases}
   a_1 = A + (-\frac{1}{2})^{1}B + \frac{2}{3}a_2\cdot 1 \\
   a_2 = A + (-\frac{1}{2})^{2}B + \frac{2}{3}a_2\cdot 2
\end{cases}
$$
which are solved by $B = \frac{4}{9}a_2-\frac{4}{3}a_1$ and $A = \frac{1}{3}a_1 - \frac{4}{9}a_2$.
Substituting the calculated coefficients into the general formula, we get :
$$
a_n = b_n + c_n = \\
A + (-2)^{-n}B + \frac{2}{3}a_2\cdot n = \\ (\frac{1}{3}a_1 - \frac{4}{9}a_2) + (-\frac{1}{2})^{n}\cdot(\frac{4}{9}a_2-\frac{4}{3}a_1)+(\frac{2}{3}a_2\cdot n)
$$
